# Адаптивная верстка, CSS

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Я пишу макет сайта и не могу понять как сделать так чтобы на экранах с разными разрешениями он смотрелся опрятно.Когда уменьшаю окно браузера все начинает хаотично менять свои места и получается некрасиво.Что делать?Уже примерно половина макета написана.

Comment: Изучи медиа запросы и `bootstrap` ,
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp,    http://bootstrap-ru.com/

Comment: А при чем тут кроссбраузерность? Вы про адаптивный дизайн читайте.

Comment: Используй css фраймворки, к примеру - Bootstrap. Так же рекомендую ознакомится с технологией Flexbox.

Comment: Однозначного ответа на вопрос «Как сделать чтобы было опрятно и красиво?» дать невозможно. Нужно разбираться с конкретными проблемами.

Answer (score 5):

Для этого используйте медиа-запросы CSS. В примере лишь одна из возможностей использования медиа-запросов. Например такая конструкция `@media (max-width: 575px) {}` будет применять свойства к селекторам, когда ширина клиентской области будет не больше 575px. А такая конструкция `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}` будет применять свойства к селекторам, когда ширина клиентской области будет не больше 991px и не меньше 768px.

```css
.col{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .col{
     width: 100%;   
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col{
     width: 49%;   
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
 .col{
     width: 32%;   
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col{
     width: 15%;   
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Использование медиа-запросов</title>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="col">col 1</div>
  <div class="col">col 2</div>
  <div class="col">col 3</div>
  <div class="col">col 4</div>
  <div class="col">col 5</div>
  <div class="col">col 6</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Так же советую вам изучить [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)